# Купить домен плюс бесплатный хостинг страницы заглушки

Tags: хостинг

С помощью **GitHub Pages** создал знакомым сайт визитку. И поскольку **Angular** и **Bootstrap** натянется с **CDN**, а кастомные стили и скрипты в самом файле - то у меня получился всего один HTML файл размером 25 kB. Обычная страница заглушка.

**Вопрос**: Хочу купить домен и прикрутить к нему эту страницу. Предоставляют ли продавцы доменов бесплатно хотя бы 1 Mb для размещения статичной страницы?

Или легче создать им отдельный **GitHub** аккаунт и прикрутить домен к нему?

Comment: я за `github`, сам так делал. Плюс в том, что можно юзать `git` и бесплатная защита от `ddos` атак.

Answer (score 2):

Можно купить домен отдельно, а для статических страниц использовать, например, облачное хранилище Selectel. Это не бесплатная услуга, но по опыту использования могу сказать, что хранение небольшого статического сайта обойдется считанные рубли в год (в зависимости размера и исходящего трафика). По сравнению со стоимостью продления домена - это очень незначительно.

- Обзор на habrahabr: [Статические сайты в облачном хранилище](https://habrahabr.ru/company/selectel/blog/216983/)
- Информация на сайте Selectel (калькулятор цены там же): [Облачное хранилище](https://selectel.ru/services/cloud-storage/)

  - Цена 0,0220$ (около 1,3 р.) за хранение в месяц - не минимальная. По факту, если хранить 10 Мб, то это 0,03 р. в месяц. Поэтому 10 р., которые они кладут на счет при регистрации (если, конечно, эту халяву еще не прикрыли), вам может хватить очень на долго.

Дисклэймер: в Selectel не работаю, просто пользуюсь их облачным хранилищем.

Другие варианты: [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com/) или [статический сайт на Bitbucket.org](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/publishing-a-website-on-bitbucket-cloud-221449776.html).

- Минус bitbucket - нельзя прикрутить свой домен, можно использовать только домены 3 уровня вида `имя_пользователя.bitbucket.io` (или `имя_команды.bitbucket.io`).
- Дополнительный плюс github pages - возможность использовать генератор статических сайтов [jekyll](https://jekyllrb.com) для автоматического преобразования страничек из markdown в html.

Answer (score 1):

есть бесплатные хостинги, с бесплатными доменами 3го уроня....например https://www.awardspace.com/web-hosting/free-shared-hosting-main/free-shared-hosting